# how to change the date format in the objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

after selecting the date from the date picker, i am getting the date in the format in view like yy/mm/dd .

i want to the date format in my view like mm/dd/yy.
how can i do this.

Comment: Use an NSDateFormatter for a specific format. Otherwise the format will be gleaned from various localization settings that the user sets in the Settings app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following snippet to convert the date to the format you desire. Note that month use uppercase 'MM' in the format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

For a full list of the formats available, have a look at the [Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns). With a few minor exceptions, these formats are all supported on the iPhone.